# IBM MQ client for Mac OS

Tags: macos, ibm-mq

Was trying to locate the IBM MQ client installable ( and dependent libraries ) for Mac operating system, but could not.
Tried couple of variations from the IBM site, but always ends up getting the error :

```
package MQSeriesMsg_cs-<any-version-i-take>.x86_64 is intended for a different operating system
```

Anyone faced this error and was able to get a proper version for MacOS,please suggest.

Comment: Which API are you interested in using?  It should be possible to download the Java-All client and use it on Mac OS for IBM MQ Classes for Java or IBM MQ Classes for JMS.  In searching I found a company called "[Willow Technology](http://www.willowtech.com/mqclients/mqclient_mac.htm) that sells MQ Client ported to Mac OS.  I do not know anything about this company but if you require more than the IBM MQ Classes for JMS or Java this may be the only option.

Comment: The requirement is just to create a queue, push/publish some messages and consume some messages. The original intention is to use node program to be able to connect to IBM MQ for the above functionality. Inline, when verified, came to know that we need to install the MQ client and use it in the node program.

Comment: Can you confirm what is node  program?

Comment: do you mean node.js?

Comment: Willow Technology are a porting house that create MQ Clients on platforms that IBM don't do, using the licensed code base.

Comment: @JoshMc Yes. Node.js based program.

Comment: Have you looked at MQLight?

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for this, IBM now have an official toolkit.  See this link: https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/tutorials/mq-macos-dev/

Comment: It is licensed for development only.